# Jquery - Insert dynamically created div child in his right position

Tags: jquery

I haven't been using jQuery for a long while and I need some reminder for a certain task I have.

Running jQuery 1.7, I want to insert a dynamically created div in his respective position. I think it's easier to explain via an example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/s9m3ge3e/

If we click 1, 2 and 3 everything is well. Then I remove 2 and re-click 2 again. What I get is:
1
3
2.

What I really want is:
1
2
3

To sum up, what do I choose instead of the "append"?

`$("#container").append('<div id="text_'+num+'">'+ num + ' Added</div>')`
I don't want 2 to be appended to the end, I want him to be in his right position between 1 and 3.

Edit: Also be aware that the solution should be generic. It's 3 "buttons" this time but could eventually become 4, 5 etc

P.S:  The fiddle is a very abstracted version of what I have in real life. Disregard the horrible code I wrote to visualize it, I'm aware of it. Just wanted to write a quick example of the issue I'm encountering.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here we go.

Here's a pure jquery solution (with a dash of CSS):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button').click(function(){
        
        if ($('#container div').eq($('button').index(this)).attr('class') === 'hide') {
            $(this).text('Del ' + ($('button').index(this) + 1));
            $('#container div').eq($('button').index(this)).attr('class','show');
        }

        else {
            $(this).text('Add ' + ($('button').index(this) + 1));
            $('#container div').eq($('button').index(this)).attr('class','hide');
        }

    });

});
```

```css
.hide {
display: none;
}

.show {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">Add 1</button>
<button type="button">Add 2</button>
<button type="button">Add 3</button>
<button type="button">Add 4</button>
<button type="button">Add 5</button>

<div>
---------------------
<div id="container">
<div class="hide">1 Added</div>
<div class="hide">2 Added</div>
<div class="hide">3 Added</div>
<div class="hide">4 Added</div>
<div class="hide">5 Added</div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

## Second Attempt (dynamic divs only)

Here is an alternative pure jQuery approach which adds and removes dynamic divs.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button').click(function(){
        
        if ($(this).text() === ('Add ' + ($('button').index(this) + 1))) {
            $(this).text('Del ' + ($('button').index(this) + 1));

            if ($('#container div').length === 0) {
                $('#container').append('<div class="show" data-index="' + $('button').index(this) + '">' + ($('button').index(this) + 1) + ' Added</div>');
            }

            else if ($('#container div[data-index="' + $('button').index(this) + '"').length > 0) {
                $('#container div[data-index="' + $('button').index(this) + '"').attr('class','show');
            } 
            
            else {
                var added = false;

                for (i = ($('#container div').length - 1); i >= -1; i--) {
                    if ((added !== true) && (i === -1)) {
                        $('#container').prepend('<div class="show" data-index="' + $('button').index(this) + '">' + ($('button').index(this) + 1) + ' Added</div>');
                        added = true;  
                    }

                    if ((added !== true) && ($('#container div').eq(i).attr('data-index') < $('button').index(this))) {
                        $('<div class="show" data-index="' + $('button').index(this) + '">' + ($('button').index(this) + 1) + ' Added</div>').insertAfter($('#container div').eq(i));
                        added = true;
                    }
                }
             }
          }

        else {
            $(this).text('Add ' + ($('button').index(this) + 1));
            $('#container div[data-index="' + $('button').index(this) + '"]').attr('class','hide');
        }

    });

});
```

```css
.hide {
display: none;
}

.show {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">Add 1</button>
<button type="button">Add 2</button>
<button type="button">Add 3</button>
<button type="button">Add 4</button>
<button type="button">Add 5</button>

<div>
---------------------
<div id="container">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rounin, your code is doing what I wanted it to do, however, there is a reason I'm creating the "x Added" row dynamically. In my original situation, the "x Added" row is an handlebars template I am creating on the fly. So your solution will not work for me

Comment: I had another bash at it and came up with a solution which generates divs dynamically. I used three jQuery methods (`append()`, `prepend()`, `insertAfter()`) and an HTML5 custom `data-*` attribute. See the "Second Attempt" above.

Comment: Funnily enough I do use  data-index in the actual problem I have and I see that this solution generally works. I might have to alter some of what you wrote here to fit my actual problem but I believe this solves the main issue. Will only be able to find it out on Sunday but I'm gonna choose this as the correct answers as you are using append, prepend, insertAfter and eq which was the general way I think my solution needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all I really appreciate the way you have asked your question so +1 for that, newbies should leard the way of asking question from it.

Now forgive me for ugly code but thats all i could do in hurry, I hope this is what you wanted. 
Replace your js code with this:

```
$(".btnAdd").on('click', addText);
var inserted = false;
function addText() {
  var num = this.id.substring(4);
  if($('#container div').length){
  var no_of_div = $('#container div').length;
  $('#container div').each(function(){
    var no = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    if(inserted)
    return;
    if(parseInt(no)<parseInt(num)){

                $('<div id="text_'+num+'">'+ num + ' Added</div>').insertAfter($(this));
        inserted=true;

    } 
    else{
       $('<div id="text_'+num+'">'+ num + ' Added</div>').insertBefore($(this));
    }
  });
  if($('#container div').length===no_of_div){
     $("#container").append('<div id="text_'+num+'">'+ num + ' Added</div>');
  }
  }
  else{
      $("#container").append('<div id="text_'+num+'">'+ num + ' Added</div>');
      }

  changeBtnToRemove(this.id);

  inserted = false;
}

function changeBtnToRemove(id) {
  var $id = $("#" + id);
  $id.text($id.text().replace('Add', 'Del'));
  $id.removeClass('btnAdd').addClass('btnRemove');
  $id.off().on('click', removeText);
}

function removeText() {
  var num = this.id.substring(4);
  $("#text_" + num).remove();

  var $id = $("#" + this.id);
  $id.text($id.text().replace('Del', 'Add'));
  $id.removeClass('btnRemove').addClass('btnAdd');
  $id.off().on('click', addText);
}
```

I made this code on your fiddle so obviously it worked for me.
*I hope it helps*

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately in  your solution clicking 1,2,3 results in 1,3,2 so we're not quite there yet :)

Answer (score 0):

As this is just an example to your actual problem, I'm not sure that my answer will work for you or not.

My approach to handle such problem will be to manage a json:

```
var items = [{id:1,text:"btn 1",isSelected:false},{id:2,text:"btn 2",isSelected:false},{id:3,text:"btn 3",isSelected:false}]
```

Now, when a button is clicked, I'll pass its id to the function and change the json:

```
function addText(id)
{
    for(var count = 0;count<items.length;count++)
    {
        if(items[count].id == id){items[count].id = true; break;}
    }
    //Now I'll take the text for all selected buttons and add it to the div
    var text = "";
    for(var count = 0;count<items.length;count++)
    {
        if(items[count].isSelected ==tr
    }
}
```